# Как создать ValueObject без инкапсуляции?

Tags: c#, ооп, code-style, ddd

```cs
class CalculationResult<T>
{
    public static CalculationResult<T> Success(T result)
    {
        return new CalculationResult<T>
        {
            IsSuccess = true,
            Result = result
        };
    }

    public static CalculationResult<T> Failure(Exception error)
    {
        return new CalculationResult<T>
        {
            IsSuccess = false,
            Error = error
        };
    }

    public bool IsSuccess { get; private set; }

    public Exception Error { get; private set; }

    public T Result { get; private set; }
}
```

Класс `CalculationResult<T>` использует инкапсуляцию, чтобы задать контракт:

- если `IsSuccess == true`, то `Result` задан, вычисление завершилось без исключений
- если `IsSuccess == false`, то `Result` не задан, вычисление завершилось с исключением

Пользователь этого класса не имеет возможность изменить его поведение и нарушить консистентность данных.

По code-style на работе я не могу использовать инкапсуляцию. Данные и методы, с ними работающие, должны быть строго разделены. Поэтому фабричные методы выделяются в отдельный интерфейс:

```cs
interface ICalculationResultBuilder
{
    CalculationResult<T> Success<T>(T result);
    CalculationResult<T> Failure<T>(Exception error);
}
```

При этом все `private set;` я вынужден заменить по крайней мере на `internal set;`. Это чревато тем, что теперь пользователь класса может проигнорировать `ICalculationResultBuilder` и сделать так:

```cs
new CalculationResult<int>
{
    IsSuccess = true,
    Error = new Exception(),
    Result = 42
};
```

Подскажите другие средства языка и способы гарантированно ограничить пользователя в способах прострелить себе ногу?

Comment: Конструкторы не подходят, т.к. содержат минимальную логику, а значит мы воспользуемся инкапсуляцией =)

Comment: Эмм... Бежать с такой работы.

Comment: `По code-style на работе я не могу использовать инкапсуляцию.` wat?

Comment: `При этом все private set; я вынужден заменить по крайней мере на internal set;` почему?

Comment: `Данные и методы, с ними работающие, должны быть строго разделены.` ну раз у вас code style на работе гении пишут, вы можете создать вложенный в CalculationResult класс `CalculationResult.CalculationResultBuilder : ICalculationResultBuilder`, который будет иметь доступ к приватным полям родителя

Comment: @tym32167 > почему? потому что я буду обращаться к ним из другого класса

Comment: > вы можете создать вложенный в CalculationResult класс

Можете оформить в виде ответа, если лучше не придумаем - зачтем)

Comment: @tym32167 да, паттерн Паблик Морозов

Comment: @PashaPash `Паблик Морозов`, такого я ещё не слышал :)

Comment: А не против небольшое обсуждение развести на тему Паблик Морозовых? Интересно услышать, как вы аргументировали бы не использовать этот паттерн

Comment: Основной аргумент за Паблика Морозова в моем случае: у нас большая кодовая база написана в таком стиле, и никому не хочется отходить от устоявшейся практики, какой бы стремной она не была.

Если писать новый код по другому, то новичку будет сложно освоиться в проекте

Comment: Бывают и другие странные аргументы, например то что выделенный интерфейс можно будет замокать и т.д.

Только вот кажется, что доменная модельl должна тестироваться без моков вообще, т.к. это больше тема про уровень сервиса и датамапперов.

Кажется, что Паблики Морозовы говорят о плохом расслоении приложения: то что должно быть доменной моделью, используется на вшених слоях, а отсюда и требования к максимальному упрощению до тупого списка полей

Comment: `Основной аргумент за Паблика Морозова ... никому не хочется` если ваша цель писать код так, как всем хочется, то это да, аргумент. Если же вы хотите написать гибкое и поддерживаемое приложение, то по сути никого не должно интересовать, кому чего хочется.

Comment: `кажется, что доменная модельl должна тестироваться без моков вообще` да, если она состоит из одного класса, который ни с чем не взаимодействует. Как, например, вы будете писать unit тест на класс, если он работает с 5ю другими классами из вашей модели?

Comment: `Как, например, вы будете писать unit тест  ...` верно, никак. Но ведь это не означает, что сущности типа моего `Result` нельзя создавать через статические методы или конструкторы, их же мокать точно не надо?

Comment: вы прыгаете с темы на тему. Доменная модель и юнит тестирование никаким боком на связаны с `нельзя создавать через статические методы или конструкторы`